# Pass Cursor objects through intents to another activity in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent, cursor

I have a recyclerview adapter that displays data in a list view which data were populated via cursor. I would like to extend further by setting a click to each list item and pass an intent of values to another Activity like a detail activity.

Adapter.class

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.Holder> {

/* ViewHolder for each insect item */
public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView friendlyName, scientificName, dangerLevel;
    ImageView image;


    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        friendlyName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.friendlyName);
        scientificName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.scientificName);
        dangerLevel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);



    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}

private Cursor mCursor;
private Context mContext;

public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mCursor = cursor;
}

@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bugs_list_item, parent, false);
    return new Holder(view);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {

    int insectname = mCursor.getColumnIndex(BugsContract.BugsEntry.COLUMN_FRIENDLYNAME);
    int scienceName = mCursor.getColumnIndex(BugsContract.BugsEntry.COLUMN_SCIENTIFICNAME);
    int id = mCursor.getColumnIndex(BugsContract.BugsEntry._ID);
    int dangerlevel = mCursor.getColumnIndex(BugsContract.BugsEntry.COLUMN_DANGERLEVEL);
    int insectImage = mCursor.getColumnIndex(BugsContract.BugsEntry.COLUMN_IMAGEASSET);

    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);

    String insectRName = mCursor.getString(insectname);
    String scienceRName = mCursor.getString(scienceName);
    String insectRImage = mCursor.getString(insectImage);
    int dangerlevelInt = mCursor.getInt(dangerlevel);


    String dangerString = "" + dangerlevelInt;

    holder.dangerLevel.setText(dangerString);

    holder.friendlyName.setText(insectRName);
    holder.scientificName.setText(scienceRName);


}

private int getDangerColor(int danger) {
    int priorityColor = 0;
    int[] colorDangerarray = mContext.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.dangerColors);

    switch(danger) {
        case 1: priorityColor = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, colorDangerarray[0]);
            break;
        case 2: priorityColor = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, colorDangerarray[1]);
            break;
        case 3: priorityColor = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, colorDangerarray[2]);
            break;
        default: break;
    }
    return priorityColor;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mCursor.getCount();
}

/**
 * Return the {@link Insect} represented by this item in the adapter.
 *
 * @param position Adapter item position.
 *
 * @return A new {@link Insect} filled with this position's attributes
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if position is out of the adapter's bounds.
 */
public Insect getItem(int position) {
    if (position < 0 || position >= getItemCount()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Item position is out of adapter's range");
    } else if (mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        return new Insect(mCursor);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

A model class that implements parceleable

```
public class Insect implements Parcelable {
private static final String TAG = Insect.class.getSimpleName();


//Common name
public int id;

public String name;
//Latin scientific name
public String scientificName;
//Classification order
public String classification;
//Path to image resource
public String imageAsset;
//1-10 scale danger to humans
public int dangerLevel;

/**
 * Create a new Insect from discrete values
 */
public Insect(String name, String scientificName, String classification, String imageAsset, int dangerLevel) {
    this.name = name;
    this.scientificName = scientificName;
    this.classification = classification;
    this.imageAsset = imageAsset;
    this.dangerLevel = dangerLevel;
}

/**
 * Create a new Insect from a database Cursor
 */
public Insect(Cursor cursor) {
    //TODO: Create a new insect from cursor

    this.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BugsContract.BugsEntry.COLUMN_FRIENDLYNAME));
    this.scientificName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BugsContract.BugsEntry.COLUMN_SCIENTIFICNAME));
    this.classification = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BugsContract.BugsEntry.COLUMN_CLASSIFICATION));
    this.imageAsset = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BugsContract.BugsEntry.COLUMN_IMAGEASSET));
    this.dangerLevel = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BugsContract.BugsEntry.COLUMN_DANGERLEVEL)));
}

public Insect() {

}

/**
 * Create a new Insect from a data Parcel
 */
protected Insect(Parcel in) {
    this.name = in.readString();
    this.scientificName = in.readString();
    this.classification = in.readString();
    this.imageAsset = in.readString();
    this.dangerLevel = in.readInt();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(scientificName);
    dest.writeString(classification);
    dest.writeString(imageAsset);
    dest.writeInt(dangerLevel);
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public static final Creator<Insect> CREATOR = new Creator<Insect>() {
    @Override
    public Insect createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Insect(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Insect[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Insect[size];
    }
};
}
```

I would like to know how to declare an intent that houses the data to another activity and how to get data from the intent in the next activity

Answer (score 0):

As long as you've implemented parcelable on your model class you can easily pass your object around like you usually would passing primitive data via `putExtra()` method.

For the sender activity:

```
Intent receiverIntent = new Intent(this, Receiver.class);
receiverIntent.putExtra("key", ParcelableObject);
startActivity(receiverIntent);
```

As for the receiver class, you just make an intent object to get the `parcelableExtra` in the `onCreate()` method.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
ParcelableClass parcelableObject;
parcelableObject = i.getParcelableExtra("key");
```

voila, that should do.

Comment: Now the ParcelableObject should be the cursor or the model object, that's what am not clear about from your answer what will be ParcelableObject

Comment: Clearly it should be from your `Insect` class object, since you pass the `cursor` to the class constructor (meaning the insect object is constructed from your cursor), passing the `Insect` object should meet your needs. :)